# how to put array bad words in file .txt php

Tags: php

i am trying to use this code to filter bad word and it work good but i want to put the bad words in .txt file i try different ways but did not work

```
$GLOBALS['bad_words']= array('truck' => true, 'shot' => true);

function containsBadWord($str){
    $str= trim($str);
    $str= preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);
    $word_list= explode(" ", $str);
    foreach($word_list as $word){
        if( isset($GLOBALS['bad_words'][$word]) ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code for writing to a file

Comment: the bad words in `array('truck' => true, 'shot' => true);` i want truck shot etc in txt file

Comment: You say _I try different ways_. So, what _exactly_ did you try? What did you expect from what you tried and what was the result instead?

Comment: i try `file('/path/to/bad_word.txt');` `file_get_contents` and to make it `json` It did not work

Comment: Clbuttic filtering. Hope none of your users are from [Scunthorpe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: @Sammitch It's just an example :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write bad words into a file, you can use [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and store it in JSON using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['bad_words']= array('truck' => true, 'shot' => true);

file_put_contents('/path/to/bad_word.txt',json_encode($GLOBALS['bad_words']));
```

**#Update:**

To get bad words from this file, you can use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$bad_words = json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/bad_word.txt'),true);
$GLOBALS['bad_words'] = $bad_words;
```

Comment: Thank you
But I'm trying to get truck word and shot from bad_word.txt like this 

`$bad_word = file_get_contents('/path/to/bad_word.txt');`
`$GLOBALS['bad_words']= $bad_word;`

Comment: @Destroyer Added an update. But, are you going to continuously read and write in your file? Or is it static?`